# exccute web application testcases other than JUnit

Tags: java, testing

How to execute web application unit testcases other than JUnit? any other tool to execute that web application test cases?

Answer (score 3):

JUnit is a nice framework for orchestrating all different kinds of tests, but for web testing you generally need some more tools. [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) provides everything you need -- help with the communications, form submittal, parsing, etc. You can use it along with JUnit, or some other framework like [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sahi Automation Testing Tool](http://sahi.co.in/w/).

In that you can test the user Interface as well as the testcases you have to test.

And also it generates the reports of the testcases.